# Invalid token in class const C#

Tags: c#

I know this question has asked here before but I am unable to find what is wrong with my code.

```
      class Slider
     {
        public int const DEFAULT_SIZE = 20; // Problem is here. Invalid token in class 

    private int rise { get; set; }
    private int run { get; set; }
    private int size { get; set; }

    int positionX = 0;
    int positionY = 0;

    private int leftBoundX { get; set;}
    private int leftBoundY { get; set; }

    private int rightBoundX { get; set; }
    private int rightBoundY { get; set; }

    // Constructor
    Slider()
    {
        size = DEFAULT_SIZE; 
    }

    private void Bound()
    {
        if (positionX > leftBoundX)
            positionX = rightBoundX;
        else if (positionY > leftBoundY)
            positionY = rightBoundY;
        else if (positionX > leftBoundX)
            positionX = rightBoundX;
        else if (positionX > leftBoundX)
            positionX = rightBoundX;
        }
```

I googled stuff, they told me to include System.Collection and I did but still same error

Comment: Please note what you have tried and where the previously suggested methods failed.

Comment: Have you tried the [Google](http://bit.ly/QXiPOo) thing?

Answer (score 7):

The `const` modifier has to be *before* the type of the constant. You want:

```
public const int DEFAULT_SIZE = 20;
```

Or to follow .NET naming conventions:

```
public const int DefaultSize = 20;
```